# Switch Azure Functions from "Consumption plan" to "Premium plan"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Does anybody know, how can you change Azure Functions that are on "consumption plan" to "premium plan"? I cannot redeploy them again, and I need to switch them to a premium plan. I didn't find any relevant manuals how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use azure cli command [az resource update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-update).

Note: I have the azure function and premium plan **in the same resource group**.

1.Get the resource id of your premium plan via azure portal or commands. The screenshot shows how to get resource id via azure portal(Regarding how to Create a Premium plan using azure cli command, you can refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan#create-a-premium-plan), after step 9.):

[image]

2.Then you can use the azure cli command below to update the plan to premium:

```
az resource update --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" --name "your azure function name" --resource-group "xxx" --set properties.serverFarmId="the resource id from step 1"
```

The test result as below, and after executing the command, nav to your function app -> and you can see the plan is changed to the premium plan(it may take a few minutes):

[image]

By the way, if you don't have azure cli installed locally, you can run these commands from azure portal as per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Thanks! Just for reference, if the function and the plan are in 2 separate group then how should the command be changed?